# How to separate monthly and daily filenames on python list into two separate lists?

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

```
allFiles =['https://myurl.com/something//something_01-01-2020.csv',
           'https://myurl.com/something//something_01-02-2020.csv', 
           'https://myurl.com/something//something_03-2020.csv'
           'https://myurl.com/something//something_01-03-2020.csv',
           'https://myurl.com/something//something_04-2020.csv'...]
```

How can I separate monthly and daily files into two separate lists?

Desired output:

```
   daily = ['https://myurl.com/something//something_01-01-2020.csv',
           'https://myurl.com/something//something_01-02-2020.csv', 
           'https://myurl.com/something//something_01-03-2020.csv']

   monthly = ['https://myurl.com/something//something_03-2020.csv',
              'https://myurl.com/something//something_04-2020.csv']
```

I was trying the bellow but unsuccessfully:

```
 daily = [ x for x in allFiles if "%m-%Y.csv" not in x ]
```

Could someone please help? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution making use of `regex` to identify daily and monthly date pattern's,

```
import re

daily_pattern = re.compile(r"\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}.csv")
monthly_pattern = re.compile(r"\d{2}-\d{4}.csv")

monthly, daily = [], []

for f in allFiles:
    if daily_pattern.search(f):
        daily.append(f)
    elif monthly_pattern.search(f):
        monthly.append(f)
    else:
        print('invalid pattern %s' % f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the url to get only the part you want, then count the hyphens to see the format of the date:

```
monthly = []
daily = []
for url in all_files:
  # splits the url string by '/', returns only the part after the last '/'
  filename = url.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
  # same as before but split by '_' and getting only similar to 01-01-2020.csv
  
  datestring = filename.rsplit('_', 1)[-1]
  datestring_hyphens = datestring.count('-')

  if datestring_hyphens == 1:
    monthly.append(datestring)
  elif date_string_hyphens == 2:
    daily.append(datestring)
```

Answer (score 0):

first create a function allowing to sort the URLs in order to classify those being days and those being months

```
 allFiles =['https://myurl.com/something//something_01-01-2020.csv',
       'https://myurl.com/something//something_01-02-2020.csv', 
       'https://myurl.com/something//something_03-2020.csv'
       'https://myurl.com/something//something_01-03-2020.csv',
       'https://myurl.com/something//something_04-2020.csv']

def month_or_day(string):
    return len(string.split('_')[1].split(".")[0].split('-'))
```

Then create a dataframe to apply this function to each URL

```
df=pd.DataFrame(allFiles,columns=['URL'])
df['Month_day']=0
df['intermediate'] =  pd.Series(allFiles).apply(lambda x : month_or_day(x))
```

You get the URLS separation as follows:

```
print('Month : ',df[df['intermediate']==2]['URL'].tolist())
print('')
print('Day : ',df[df['intermediate']==3]['URL'].tolist())
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions:

```
import re

daily_pattern = r"""
    ^       # Start of string
    .+?     # Match anything except newline (not greedy)
    \d{2}   # Two numerical values.
    -       # Hyphen
    \d{2}   # Two numerical values.
    -       # Hyphen
    \d{4}   # Four numerical values.
    \.\w+   # File extension with escaped period.
    $       # End of string
"""

# Compile with re.M (ignore case) and re.X (handle pattern verbosity)
p = re.compile(daily_pattern, flags=re.I | re.X)

daily = [f for f in allFiles if p.match(f)]
monthly = [f for f in allFiles if not f in daily]
```

EDIT: Updated to include more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

May be like this

```
month_files = [f for f in allFiles if len(f.rpartition('_')[2].split('-'))==2]

day_files = [f for f in allFiles if len(f.rpartition('_')[2].split('-'))==3]
```

`rpartition` will split the file on `_` and give you 3 items like `['somename','_','the date/month .csv']` you can filter on the date part with split and length checking.

with `rpartition` it'll work even if the filename has multiple `_`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex here

**Ex:**

```
import re

allFiles =['https://myurl.com/something//something_01-01-2020.csv',
           'https://myurl.com/something//something_01-02-2020.csv', 
           'https://myurl.com/something//something_03-2020.csv',
           'https://myurl.com/something//something_01-03-2020.csv',
           'https://myurl.com/something//something_04-2020.csv']

daily = []
monthly = []

for i in allFiles:
    if re.search(r"_(\d+\-\d+\.csv)$", i):
        monthly.append(i)
    else:
        daily.append(i)

print(daily)
print(monthly)
```

**Output:**

```
['https://myurl.com/something//something_01-01-2020.csv', 'https://myurl.com/something//something_01-02-2020.csv', 'https://myurl.com/something//something_01-03-2020.csv']

['https://myurl.com/something//something_03-2020.csv', 'https://myurl.com/something//something_04-2020.csv']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is no other "_" in the file name:

```
monthly = [file for file in allFiles if len(file.split('_')[1].split('-')) == 2]
daily = [file for file in allFiles if len(file.split('_')[1].split('-')) == 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Notice that you have a mistake in your example, there is a missing comma.
2. Your issue is well-suited for regular expressions.

```py
import re

allFiles =['https://myurl.com/something//something_01-01-2020.csv',
           'https://myurl.com/something//something_01-02-2020.csv', 
           'https://myurl.com/something//something_03-2020.csv',
           'https://myurl.com/something//something_01-03-2020.csv',
           'https://myurl.com/something//something_04-2020.csv']

dailyRegexp = re.compile(r".*\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\d\d\.csv$")
isDaily = lambda fn: dailyRegexp.match(fn)

daily = [fn for fn in allFiles if isDaily(fn)]
monthly = [fn for fn in allFiles if not isDaily(fn)]

print("Daily:", daily)
print("Monthly:", monthly)
```

Explanation of the regexp:

- `.*` is any character (`.`), repeated arbitrary times (`*`)
- `\d` is any digit
- `-` is just literal character `-`, no special meaning
- `\.` is a dot character (escaped by backslash to prevent special meaning)
- `csv` is literal string, no special meaning
- `$` is end of string

Notice also `r` before the string. It signifies raw string that prevents Python to interpret `\` as special character. More info:

- Regular expressions: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html
- Raw string: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals